# Selenium opening multiple tabs not working

Tags: selenium

I've tried this code snippet to automate opening the same url 'google.com' in multiple tabs in Firefox. But it still gets opened in new Windows only. Since I just want to open that url only, I don't want to get the handle to switch back and forth.

Can you please help me find what's wrong with my code:

```
public class MultipleTabsWebinar {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    List drivers = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.out.println("Hello World Test on AMS148");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://10.3.3.148");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
        drivers.add(driver);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < drivers.size(); i++){
        ((WebDriver) drivers.get(i)).close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're opening a new separate browser instance with each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, but then how can I open 15 tabs and go to the above url in all the 15 tabs

Comment: Just do not instantiate a new WebDriver in each iteration, but share a single instance. Remaining parts of the code should be fine (sending the key combination is afaik the only way to open a new tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
    jse.executeScript("window.open('https://google.com');");
    }
```

This should allow you to open Google search page in multiple new tabs

Note that (as was mentioned in comments) you don't need to initialize `WebDriver` instance inside a loop